# Редактор Xamarin, изменение внешнего вида приложения

Tags: android, gui, xamarin, конструктор

Как можно убрать блок выделенный красным на фото, чтобы layout занимал весь экран? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

это `ActionBar`, он убирается через стили. У большинства стилей есть модификация `NoActionBar`, например `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`